# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.common: "No module named _md5"

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am running Apache2 on Ubuntu 9 with python 2.6.2 installed. I get the following error when I try to access a page on my django application:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 42, in load_middleware raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.common: "No module named _md5"

Here is my wsgi file:

> import os, sys
>   sys.path.append('/etc/apache2/sites-available/')
>   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dynamicuddi.settings'
>   import django.core.handlers.wsgi
>   application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

From what I've read I think it's a python path problem but I haven't seen an actual solution to this that has worked. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it's all running on its own box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to wrap this up, we ended up re-installing the OS. I know this is a cop out but it fixed the problem for us.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to append to python path you project directory and parent one

```
sys.path.append('path_to_dynamicuddi_project')
sys.path.append('path_to_dynamicuddi_parent_dir')
```

Comment: Where would I put this? In my settings.py file? or in my .bashrc file?

Comment: This is an import problem for a global package, not his project (as the exception comes from `django.middleware.common`

Comment: So I have to add this to .bashrc? but for which user; root? I'm guessing apache runs under root and I would have to add this to the root user?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a pathing issue, like [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082651/django-cms-improperlyconfigured-error-importing-middleware-cms-middleware-media).

I think it's finding the django.middleware.common module just fine and attempting to import it, but that module is causing an ImportError by trying to import "_md5."

1. You might want to have a look at this rather lengthy thread where Graham Dumpleton attempts to address this very problem: http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg30630.html
2. <strike>Failing that, I would recommend you post the contents of the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple from your settings.py.</strike>
3. Also, what version of Django are you running?

Comment: +1 for option 1, -0.4 for option 2 (this doesn't have to do with his settings)

Comment: Yep, you're right,  that was my initial thought and I left it in even after I found the django-users thread. Fail.

Comment: I came across the thread by Graham already and I was secretly hoping my problem wouldn't be this complicated. I will read into it deeper some more, thanks.

Comment: Found the following comment in a config/Setup under my Python install...

"# Note that the _md5 and _sha modules are normally only built if the system does not have the OpenSSL libs containing an optimized version."

Just a thought: Do you have an up-to-date version of OpenSSL installed?

Comment: So I ran > openssl version and got the following response: OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

Comment: So when I do run ldd /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so I get libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7f35000). I'm assuming this is what they are referring to in the Graham thread; however, when I run ldd /opt/lampp/bin/httpd I do not get a libssl entry which means I have a problem? So if that is the case I'm supposed to rebuild apache?

Comment: Not sure how to proceed here, would a reinstall of apache fix this problem?

Comment: It's possible that a reinstall of Apache is your best bet. Also, this may have no impact on your problem here, but are you using virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper? I'm no python wizard, but it may be something to check out.